# Xcode 11 build failure with command PhaseScriptExecution

Tags: xcode, flutter

Recently I rain into a strange issue when I doing a flutter project. My code can build and run in android studio, but when build on Xcode, it always hit the below error during the end of the process and failed with error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code". My xcode is of the latest version 11.1. Anyone encountered the same issue and any clue to resolve it? thanks and any help is appreciated.

The detail error msg is as shown below:

```
export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
export TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
export TREAT_MISSING_BASELINES_AS_TEST_FAILURES=NO
export TeamIdentifierPrefix=7HVQ37VRT5.
export UID=501
export UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app
export UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT=NO
export USER=derrickxiang
export USER_APPS_DIR=/Users/derrickxiang/Applications
export USER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Users/derrickxiang/Library
export USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC=YES
export USE_HEADERMAP=YES
export USE_HEADER_SYMLINKS=NO
export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES=YES
export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_CLANG=YES
export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_LD=YES
export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_TAPI=YES
export USE_RECURSIVE_SCRIPT_INPUTS_IN_SCRIPT_PHASES=YES
export VALIDATE_DEVELOPMENT_ASSET_PATHS=YES_ERROR
export VALIDATE_PRODUCT=NO
export VALIDATE_WORKSPACE=NO
export VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64"
export VERBOSE_PBXCP=NO
export VERSIONING_SYSTEM=apple-generic
export VERSIONPLIST_PATH=Runner.app/version.plist
export VERSION_INFO_BUILDER=derrickxiang
export VERSION_INFO_FILE=Runner_vers.c
export VERSION_INFO_STRING=""@(#)PROGRAM:Runner  PROJECT:Runner-1""
export WRAPPER_EXTENSION=app
export WRAPPER_NAME=Runner.app
export WRAPPER_SUFFIX=.app
export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES=NO
export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=11A1027
export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL=1110
export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR=1100
export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR=1110
export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH=Runner.app/XPCServices
export YACC=yacc
export arch=undefined_arch
export variant=normal
/bin/sh -c /Users/derrickxiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ddqqlsawcqbvcocyrpnrjfejjuha/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-3B06AD1E1E4923F5004D2608.sh
```

Non-fat binary /Users/derrickxiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ddqqlsawcqbvcocyrpnrjfejjuha/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App is not x86_64. Running lipo -info:
Non-fat file: /Users/derrickxiang/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ddqqlsawcqbvcocyrpnrjfejjuha/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App is architecture: arm64
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: I am facing same issue can you help me

Comment: @MilanPansuriya, sorry i didn't get a solution in the end, but we rebuild on another pc and it works, don't know why, seems the xcode environment issue.